# update an image field as a blob type to database in QT C++

Tags: jquery, c++, sql, qt

I am trying to update an image as a blob type to database from QImage to database. I used below code do this:

```
int reportingID = 10;
    // props is QMap<QString, QVariant> fill with string and QImage as a QVariant
QSqlQuery sqlQueryImage(_db);
bool ok = sqlQueryImage.prepare("UPDATE reporting SET leftIcon = iconL WHERE id = 'ID'"
                     "VALUES (:iconL,:ID)");
qDebug() << "text: " << ok << endl;
sqlQueryImage.bindValue(":iconL", QVariant(props["left_icon"].toByteArray()));
sqlQueryImage.bindValue(":ID", QVariant(reportingID));
```

I used upper code to update QString of database and it worked correct but it didn't work for updating image. I don't know where my problem is!

Comment: Very strange update statement. Maybe it should be something like `"UPDATE reporting SET leftIcon = ':iconL' WHERE id = ':ID'"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QSqlQuery sqlQueryImage(_db);
QImage img_enrll = props["left_icon"].value<QImage>();
QByteArray arr;
QBuffer buffer(&arr);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
img_enrll.save(&buffer, "jpg");

sqlQueryImage.prepare("UPDATE reporting SET leftIcon = :iconL WHERE id = :ID");
sqlQueryImage.bindValue(":iconL", arr, QSql::InOut | QSql::Binary);
sqlQueryImage.bindValue(":ID", reportingID, QSql::InOut | QSql::Binary);

if (!sqlQueryImage.exec()) {
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "sql error (update icon): " << sqlQuery.lastError();
    return;
}
```